# using @college.name inside of an image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2.13.

I have an @college.name variable available to me in my view file.  I have a carousel of pictures (3 per school).  The names of the jpg files are in the form of `university_of_pittsburgh1.jpg`, `university_of_pittsburgh2.jpg`, and `university_of_pittsburgh3.jpg`.  I'd like to link to them by doing something like

`<%= image_tag "@college.name1.jpg" %>`

but that doesn't seem to be working.  How could I link to the pictures properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag "#{@college.name}1.jpg" %>
```

You want to use string interpolation by wrapping `@college.name` in a set of braces: #{...}

This will replace it with the actual college name, while the `1.jpg` part outside of the braces will be added on. So the above would be interpreted as:

```
<%= image_tag "university_of_pittsburgh1.jpg" %>
```

Comment: Also remember that you must use double quotes, not single quotes, when interpolating.